# How to create a Beamer overlay \cover command, dual to \uncover?

Tags: beamer, overlays

I would like to define a command `\mycover` that is dual to Beamer's `\uncover`.  In `beamerbaseoverlay.sty` the `\uncover` command is defined as

```
\newcommand{\uncover}{\alt{\beamer@fakeinvisible}{\beamer@makecovered}}
```

Therefore, my first attempt at `\mycover` simply switches the `\alt` branches:

```
\newcommand{\mycover}{\alt{\beamer@makecovered}{\beamer@fakeinvisible}}
```

Unfortunately, the first slide in `\mycover`'s overlay specification is always shown as completely invisible, even if I `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`.  Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycover}{\alt{\beamer@makecovered}{\beamer@fakeinvisible}}
\def\c@slideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
  \structure{Slide \arabic{slideinframe}}

  \uncover<1,4>{Testing} \mycover<2-3>{my cover} \uncover<1,4>{command.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The words "my cover" should be covered on exactly the same slides as the words "Testing" and "command", namely slides 2 and 3.  What actually happens, however, is that "my cover" is completely invisible on slide 2 and is properly covered on slide 3.

[image]

What is the problem with `\mycover` and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is wrong with `\uncover` for the complement? That is presumably why beamer doesn't have a `\cover` in the first place...

Comment: @vonbrand It's a good suggestion, but for complex overlays I found it conceptually cumbersome to have to complement the overlay specification each time I want to "`\cover`".  (Also, Beamer does include both `\visible` and `\invisible`, one of which is "redundant".)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I just cropped it manually in GIMP (select, then crop to selection) and built the gif from that.  I'm not sure what would be the easiest way to automate that.

Answer (score 3):

The following definition seems to produce the desired result:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\def\beamer@startmycovered{%
  \def\opaqueness<##1>##2{%
    \only<##1>{%
      \beamer@actions{%
        \expandafter\xdef\csname beamer@oldcolorhook%
        \the\beamer@coveringdepth\endcsname{\beamer@colorhook}%
        \expandafter\xdef\csname beamer@oldpgfextension%
        \the\beamer@coveringdepth\endcsname{\beamer@pgfextension}%
        {\globalcolorstrue\colorlet{beamer@freeze\the\beamer@coveringdepth}{bg}}%
        \xdef\beamer@colorhook{!##2!beamer@freeze%
          \the\beamer@coveringdepth\beamer@colorhook}%
        \gdef\beamer@pgfextension{!##2opaque}%
        \color{.}%
      }%
      {%
        \xdef\beamer@colorhook{\csname beamer@oldcolorhook%
          \the\beamer@coveringdepth\endcsname}%
        \xdef\beamer@pgfextension{\csname beamer@oldpgfextension%
          \the\beamer@coveringdepth\endcsname}%
        \color{.}%
      }}}%
  \ifnum\beamer@slideinframe<\beamer@minimum%ok, at beginning
  {%
    \beamer@saveanother%
    \advance\beamer@minimum by-\beamer@slideinframe%
    \beamer@slideinframe=\beamer@minimum%
    \beamer@uncoverbeforeactions%
    \beamer@restoreanother%
  }%
  \else%
  {%
    \beamer@saveanother%
    \advance\beamer@slideinframe by-\beamer@minimum%
    \beamer@uncoverafteractions%
    \beamer@restoreanother%
  }%
  \fi%
  \beamer@do%
%  }%
}

\long\def\beamer@makemycovered#1{\beamer@startmycovered#1\beamer@endcovered}
\def\mycover{%
\alt{\beamer@makemycovered}{\beamer@fakeinvisible}}
\def\c@slideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test frame 1}
\structure{Slide \arabic{slideinframe}}

\uncover<1,5>{Testing} \mycover<2-4>{my cover} \uncover<1,5>{command.}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test frame 2}
\structure{Slide \arabic{slideinframe}}

Testing \mycover<2,4,6>{my cover} command.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test frame 3}
\structure{Slide \arabic{slideinframe}}

\mycover<2,6>{Testing} \mycover<1-3,5-7>{my cover} command.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used your original idea, but using a variation of the original `\beamer@startcovered` used in `\beamer@makecovered`.

Although I don't use much overlay specifications in my presentations (`\pause`, `\only` and `\onslide` are enough for me) I like your idea a lot; I think this command could be a part of the official `beamer` class.

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to do what I want!  Could you explain a little bit why my first attempt failed and how your fix works?  I'd like to understand more so that I can better solve these problems on my own.  Comparing your definition of `\beamer@startmycovered` with `\beamer@startcovered` from `beamerbaseoverlay.sty`, it looks like you removed a `\beamer@actions` and a `\beamer@smuggle` from around the entire definition.  What do these do?  Thanks again!

Comment: That command doesn't seem to work for figures. Only for text.

Comment: @Droplet, the `\uncover` beamer command [can not work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305797/graphics-with-setbeamercoveredtransparent) for graphics in "transparent" mode, so no surprise this one also doesn't (It's implemented as a *fake* transparent in beamer, just by changing text and background colors).